How to Download video with blob url by Puppeteer
I am trying to download the reels from Instagram I have done all the navigation and everything I just have to write the name while running the file which Instagram Id I wanted to download the reel from, so it will download the first reel of that Instagram Id so, I am getting and error while downloading the reel because its a blob url, and I just get the code from ChatGPT but it still using the fetch method which is wrong for blob url, so anyone can help in it that how can I download the Instagram reel with blob url by Puppeteer?
here is my code
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs')
// const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter

const URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
const BROWSER_PATH =
  // '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
  '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' // Change this path to your desired browser's path

let browser

const runTest = async () => {
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      defaultViewport: null,
      executablePath: BROWSER_PATH,
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-web-security'
      ]
    })

    const pages = await browser.pages()
    let page = pages.length > 0 ? pages[0] : await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto(URL, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
      timeout: 1200000
    })

    await page.waitForSelector(
      `#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > label > input`
    )

    // Enter login credentials
    await page.type(
      '#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > label > input',
      'exampleId',
      { delay: 100 }
    )
    await page.type(
      '#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > label > input',
      'ExamplePassword',
      { delay: 100 }
    )
    await page.click('#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3)')

    // Wait for navigation after login
    await page.waitForNavigation()

    try {
      await page.waitForSelector(
        'div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1.x1dr59a3.xixxii4.x13vifvy.xeq5yr9.x1n327nk > div > div > div.xopu45v.xu3j5b3.xm81vs4.x1vjfegm > div > div.x1iyjqo2.xh8yej3 > div:nth-child(2) > span'
      )
      console.log('i am available')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('i am not available')
    }

    // x1n2onr6 x6s0dn4 x78zum5

    await page.click(
      'div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1.x1dr59a3.xixxii4.x13vifvy.xeq5yr9.x1n327nk > div > div > div.xopu45v.xu3j5b3.xm81vs4.x1vjfegm > div > div.x1iyjqo2.xh8yej3 > div:nth-child(2) > span'
    )

    await page.waitForSelector(
      'div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1.x1dr59a3.xixxii4.x13vifvy.xeq5yr9.x1n327nk > div > div > div.x10l6tqk.x1u3tz30.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1n2onr6.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1iyjqo2.x2lwn1j.xeuugli.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1 > div > div > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1d52u69.xktsk01.x1n2onr6.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1 > div > div > input'
    )

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000))

    // Enter login credentials
    await page.type(
      'div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1.x1dr59a3.xixxii4.x13vifvy.xeq5yr9.x1n327nk > div > div > div.x10l6tqk.x1u3tz30.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1n2onr6.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1iyjqo2.x2lwn1j.xeuugli.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1 > div > div > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1d52u69.xktsk01.x1n2onr6.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1 > div > div > input',
      process.argv[2],
      { delay: 100 }
    )

    await page.waitForSelector(
      'div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1.x1dr59a3.xixxii4.x13vifvy.xeq5yr9.x1n327nk > div > div > div.x10l6tqk.x1u3tz30.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1n2onr6.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1iyjqo2.x2lwn1j.xeuugli.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1 > div > div > div.x6s0dn4.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x5yr21d.x1odjw0f.x1n2onr6.xh8yej3 > div > a:nth-child(1)'
    )

    await page.click(
      'div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1.x1dr59a3.xixxii4.x13vifvy.xeq5yr9.x1n327nk > div > div > div.x10l6tqk.x1u3tz30.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1n2onr6.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1iyjqo2.x2lwn1j.xeuugli.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1 > div > div > div.x6s0dn4.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x5yr21d.x1odjw0f.x1n2onr6.xh8yej3 > div > a:nth-child(1)'
    )

    await page.waitForSelector(
      'div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.x1gryazu.xh8yej3.x10o80wk.x14k21rp.x17snn68.x6osk4m.x1porb0y > section > main > div > div.x6s0dn4.x5ur3kl.x13fuv20.x178xt8z.x1w9h7q7.x78zum5.x1pg5gke.x1s688f.xl56j7k.x1r0g7yl.x2b8uid.xtvhhri > a:nth-child(2)'
    )

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))

    await page.click(
      'div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.x1gryazu.xh8yej3.x10o80wk.x14k21rp.x17snn68.x6osk4m.x1porb0y > section > main > div > div.x6s0dn4.x5ur3kl.x13fuv20.x178xt8z.x1w9h7q7.x78zum5.x1pg5gke.x1s688f.xl56j7k.x1r0g7yl.x2b8uid.xtvhhri  a:nth-child(2)'
    )

    await page.waitForSelector(
      'div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.x1gryazu.xh8yej3.x10o80wk.x14k21rp.x17snn68.x6osk4m.x1porb0y > section > main > div > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1n2onr6.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1 > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div > a'
    )

    // await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))

    await page.click(
      'div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.x1gryazu.xh8yej3.x10o80wk.x14k21rp.x17snn68.x6osk4m.x1porb0y > section > main > div > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1n2onr6.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1 > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div > a'
    )

    await page.waitForSelector('video')

    // Extract the video source URL
    const videoSrc = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const video = document.querySelector('video')
      if (!video) {
        throw new Error('Video element not found')
      }
      return video.src
    })

    console.log('Video src:', videoSrc)

    // // Fetch the video data in the browser context
    const videoData = await page.evaluate(async videoSrc => {
      const response = await fetch(videoSrc)
      const blob = await response.blob()
      const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer()
      return Array.from(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer))
    }, videoSrc)

    // Save the video data to a file
    fs.writeFileSync('reel.mp4', Buffer.from(videoData))

    console.log('Video downloaded successfully')

    console.log('i am finished')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } finally {
    // await browser.close()
  }
}

runTest()


You want to use a FileReader on that blob:
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
  reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);  
})

You will get it back as a base64 string which you can turn into a node buffer like:
buffer = Buffer.from(videoData, 'binary')

But you can't get things like youtube videos this way and there is a size limit.
